# Sum of values for distinct pairs (order independent) and nodes in Presto

Tags: sql, graph, presto

I have a table of a large number (1000+) "Trips" in PRESTO from A to B:

```
TRIPS

Origin  |   Destination
-----------------------
NYC     |   SF
SF      |   NYC
NYC     |   MIA
MIA     |   ORD
...     |   ....
```

I've turn trips into  route counts:

```
SELECT ORIGIN, DESTINATION, COUNT(*) FROM TRIPS
GROUP BY ORIGIN, DESTINATION
```

Outputting

```
ONE-WAY ROUTES
Origin  |   Destination |   COUNT
----------------------------------
NYC     |   SF          |   3
SF      |   NYC         |   2
NYC     |   MIA         |   2
MIA     |   ORD         |   1
...     |   ....
```

I'd like to convert this into direction-agnostic counts, e.g.:

```
A       |   B           |   COUNT
----------------------------------
NYC     |   SF          |   5
NYC     |   MIA         |   2
MIA     |   ORD         |   1
...     |   ....
```

and node-specific weights:

```
NODE    |   COUNT
----------------------------------
NYC     |   7
SF      |   5
MIA     |   2
ORD     |   1
```

Would very much appreciate help with how to do this with the ONEWAYROUTES table...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` [functions](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/comparison.html) to treat symmetric pairs (pairs such as `(a,b)`, `(b,a)`) the same for counting.

```
SELECT LEAST(ORIGIN, DESTINATION),GREATEST(ORIGIN, DESTINATION), COUNT(*) 
FROM TRIPS
GROUP BY LEAST(ORIGIN, DESTINATION),GREATEST(ORIGIN, DESTINATION)
```

To get the individual node counts, use

```
SELECT node,COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT origin as node
      FROM TRIPS
      UNION ALL
      SELECT destination as node
      FROM TRIPS
     ) t
GROUP BY node
```